# tabular with multiple titles in header, some spanning multiple cells?

Tags: tables, formatting, csv, csvsimple

How do I create a table that looks like this?

```
My Title
-------------------------------------------
    Type 1                   Type 2
  ----------               ----------
colA colB colC  x    y   colF colG colH  z
-------------------------------------------
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
-------------------------------------------
```

If I have the base table in `.csv` format? I.e:

```
colA,colB,colC,x,y,colF,colG,colH,z
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii
```

target example:
[image]

I know about `csvsimple` and its `autobooktabular`, where it's possible to do

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple}

[...]

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.9\textwidth}
\csvautobooktabular[table head={\toprule  alp & bet & gam & xx & yy & F & G & H & zz \\\midrule}]{csvs/test.csv}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{blah blah blah etc.}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}
```

which overwrite the "head" column with what is specified in the `table head` and create

```
-------------------------------------------
alp  bet  gam   xx   yy   F    G    H    zz
-------------------------------------------
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  fff  ggg  hhh  iii
-------------------------------------------
```

And I can't help but feel it should be possible to use that to leave the headers from the file intact but insert the additional titles, though I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use `\csvlinetotablerow` to include the first row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.9\textwidth}
\csvautobooktabular[table head={\toprule  
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Type 1} & & &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Type 2} & \\
\cmidrule{1-3} \cmidrule{6-8} \csvlinetotablerow\\\midrule}]{test2.csv}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{blah blah blah etc.}
\label{tab:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]